# Как поместить (нарисовать) изображение в класс наследуемый от QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qpainter

Возникла такая проблема из класса mouseTracker я задаю label из класса Labella, т.к. он наследуется от QLabel по сути он должен наследовать свойства QLabel. И на примере кода я пытаюсь отрисовать изображение QPixmap, но оно не появляется.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Labella(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.flag = False
        pixmap = QPixmap('images.jpg')
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            q = QPainter()  # Painting the line

            q.begin(self)

            q.drawRect(self.firstX, self.firstY, self.x - self.firstX, self.y - self.firstY)

            q.end()
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.flag = True
        self.firstX = e.x()
        self.firstY = e.y()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.x = e.x()
        self.y = e.y()


class MouseTracker(QMainWindow):
    distance_from_center = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test = 0
        self.x = -1
        self.y = -1
        self.firstX = -1
        self.firstY = -1
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')

        lbl = Labella(self)

        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.firstX = e.x()
        self.firstY = e.y()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.x = event.x()
        self.y = event.y()

        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if not (self.firstX == -1 or self.firstY == -1):
            q = QPainter()  # Painting the line

            q.begin(self)

            q.drawRect(self.firstX, self.firstY, abs(self.x - self.firstX), abs(self.y - self.firstY))

            q.end()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если что то не понятно, оставьте комментарии.

Comment: вы не как не компануете этот `label` он у вас как бы создается, но не отображается для этого вам либо нужно сделать `label` центральным виджетом(естественно если он у вас будет единственным) это можно сделать [`self.setCentralWidget(lbl)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) либо создать дополнительное окно `QWidget` и в него при помощи компоновщика `QVBoxLayout` его скомпоновать

Comment: Labella работает? А то update по идеи вызывает paintEvent, что делает код рекурсивным. Да и не нужны эти begin/end в вашем случае, достаточно `q = QPainter(self)`. И еще, раз вы вызывали paintEvent, но не вызывали `super().paintEvent(e)`, то забудьте про `setPixmap`. Тот метод как раз и рисует картинку, а вы перекрыли метод рисования и не вызывали родительский, наверное, поэтому у вас картинки и нет :)

Comment: @gil9red я хотел оставит в описание, что к этой части кода не  стоит обращать своё внимание т.к. он не несет особой логики для заданного мной вопроса

Comment: Не думаю, что то, что я нашел не имеет смысла :) Ну, тогда после `lbl = Labella(self)` вызовите `self.setCentralWidget(lbl)`

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что вы хотите сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется этот вопрос относится к [«ошибке молотка» или «ошибка XY»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

В коде вопроса я нашел несколько ошибок, которые автору кажутся не по теме, но я считаю что они важны.

Например виджет Labella:

- понадобилось переписать `paintEvent`, вызывая родительский метод, чтобы картинка из `setPixmap` отобразилась
- убрать `self.update()`, т.к. оно вызывало перерисование виджета и было не нужно и даже вредно
- для события движения мышки вызывать `self.update()`, чтобы `paintEvent` вызвался, и, соответственно, произошло рисование квадрата на виджете.
- немного по мелочи

Код:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Labella(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = False

        pixmap = QPixmap('images.jpg')
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.size())

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.firstX = 0
        self.firstY = 0

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        super().paintEvent(e)

        if self.flag:
            painter = QPainter(self)

            painter.setPen(Qt.red)
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)

            painter.drawRect(self.firstX, self.firstY, self.x - self.firstX, self.y - self.firstY)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.flag = True
        self.firstX = e.x()
        self.firstY = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.flag = False

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.x = e.x()
        self.y = e.y()
        
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Labella()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** автор, мне кажется вам нужно разобраться последовательно с проблемами, как это было показано на примере `Labella`, а не пытаться нахрапом решить все.